# __init__ autorun methods in Python

Tags: python, oop

i'm try to parse rss and make df of tittles of them by certain words

my code have 4 parts

*Part 1, init function*

```
class News:
        def __init__(self, rss_dict, t1, t2, filename):
            self.rss_dict = rss_dict
            self.t1 = t1
            self.t2 = t2
            self.filename = filename
            self.print_headlines_test()
            self.write_and_read()
            self.certain_words()
```

*Part 2 (it's method of `class News`), Get headline methode*

```
def print_headlines_test(self):
        for key,url in self.rss_dict.items():
            feed = feedparser.parse(url)

        headlines = []

        allheadlines = []

        for newsitem in feed['items']:
            headlines.append(newsitem['title'])

        for key,url in self.rss_dict.items():
            allheadlines.extend(headlines)
        self.allheadlines = allheadlines
```

*Part 3 (it's method of `class News`), write csv file of all news and read it in pandas*

```
 def write_and_read(self):
        header = ['Tittle'] 

        with open(self.filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

            writer.writerow(i for i in header) 

            for a  in zip(self.allheadlines):
                writer.writerow((a))


            df = pd.read_csv(self.filename)

        self.df = df

        return df
```

*Part 4 (it's method of `class News`), search in pandas dataframe by certain words*

```
def certain_words(self):
        result = self.df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(self.t1, na=False,
                                    flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)).any(axis=1)
        result2 = self.df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(self.t2, na=False,
                                    flags = re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)).any(axis=1)
        return self.df[result&result2]
```

my purpose is autorun (autolaunch) my `three methods`: `print_headlines_test`, `write_and_read` and `certain words` just by

`c = News(my_dict_of_rss, target1,target2,'filename.csv')` with method `__init__` but this returns me nothing as `output`

when i'm using

```
c = News(my_dict_of_rss,target1,target2,'filename.csv')
```

and 
    `c.print_headlines_test()` or `c.write_and_read()` or `c.certain_words()` separately it is works

**TL;DR** have 1 `__init__` method and 3 `other methods` in `class`, why they didn't run automaticly by launch of `class` object with all `arguments` but launching by separately?

where is my fault?

Comment: The `write_and_read()` and `certain_words()` functions have return values, but when you're calling them from `__init__()` you aren't saving those returned values anywhere.

Comment: You have two methods which `return` there, how do you expect to get that output? Also, the return value of an `__init__` method is ignored by default; the instantiation of a class always results in an instance of the class, not of some other values.

Comment: @JohnGordon @deceze okay problem in `return`, can i solve this prolbem somehow? how can i get dataframes not with `return`?

Comment: Not to mention, an object constructor shouldn’t do *too much work*.

Comment: I think you have two basic options: 1 - don't call those functions from `__init__()`; require the client to call them himself.  2 - Instead of returning the values, those functions could save the results as an attribute on `self`.

Comment: @deceze I wanted to optimize the class so that it does all the work right away when assigning arguments, is this a bad idea?

Comment: @JohnGordon can you give me example of your point 2? i need to save `resuls` in end of the `method`? and how i could get them later?

Comment: At the end of the functions, instead of saying `return value`, you can say `self.function_result = value`.  Then other methods can access `self.function_result` to get the value.  (Of course you would have to use different names for each one.)

Comment: @JohnGordon okay i will add `self.function_result = value` at the end of the functions...but how this `values` will return in the end? should i write some more code to get output with `value`?

Comment: If it basically does all the work on instantiation and you don’t really need the instance afterwards, then it’s a function, not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure we can get your class to work. Your code does run right now, but since it seems that you are only interested in the return value from `certain_words()`, then that might have to be called separately:

```
class News:
    def __init__(self, rss_dict, t1, t2, filename):
        # init elided, but just these two functions called
        self.print_headlines_test()
        self.write_and_read()

    def print_headlines_test(self):
        # processing elided, except:
        self.allheadlines = allheadlines

    def write_and_read(self):
        # processing elided, except the next line (Note no return)
        self.df = df

    def certain_words(self):
        # processing elided, except for this return
        return self.df[result & result2]

# client code is now two lines:
c = News(my_dict_of_rss, target1, target2, 'filename.csv')
words = c.certain_words()

# If you don't care about keeping the instance 'c' around, then you can do it in one line:
words = News(my_dict_of_rss, target1, target2, 'filename.csv').certain_words()
```